# .htaccess - incorrectly redirecting even when directories exist

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the following .htaccess rules

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(/)?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-0-9]+)(/)?$ p/index.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The following redirects as expected

`https://website.com/2` -> `https://website.com/index.php?page=2`

It works for directories that do not exist

`https://website.com/UserString` -> `https://website.com/p/index.php?slug=UserString`

`https://website.com/UserString2` -> `https://website.com/p/index.php?slug=UserString2`

Works for some directories that exist

`https://website.com/list/` -> `https://website.com/list/` doesn't redirect as the ./list directory exists on the web server.

`https://website.com/blog/` -> `https://website.com/blog/` doesn't redirect as the ./blog directory exists on the web server.

But the following URL is being redirected even though the ./reminders and ./events directories exists on the web server.

`https://website.com/reminders/` -> `https://website.com/p/index.php?slug=reminders`

`https://website.com/events/` -> `https://website.com/p/index.php?slug=events`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and why it's trying to redirect for directories that exist?

Comment: The surprising part here is rather that it _does_ work for some folders. Because a RewriteCond applies to the immediately following RewriteRule only - so in this case, only for folder names that consist of nothing but digits. Your second rule, that actually matches folder names with alphanumeric characters, is not currently affected by your condition at all.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise RewriteCond applies to the immediately following RewriteRule only.

Have solved this by adding the RewriteCond before each rule.